# I'm a dangerous man!

Tags: riddle, wordplay

> I raze cities and I conquer towns,
>
> I’ll pillage a village and take it all down.
>
> While my wife is up to no good.
>
> I am sometimes mistaken, don’t mistake I!
>
> I am not one to make food.
>
> I don’t belong to a tribe.

Who am I?

---

**HINTS:**

1

> The answer is a single english word

2

> There is a fair bit of wordplay within this poem

Answer (score 4):

Seems like

> Fire

First two lines

> self explanatory.

While my wife is up to no good.

> I think wife here represents the smoke coming out of fire as its of no use.

I am sometimes mistaken, don’t mistake I!

> Sometimes a small fire is taken for granted that further causes huge damage.

I am not one to make food.

> Its used for cooking food but not one to make food.

I don’t belong to a tribe.

> Dosent belong

Comment: Not the right answer. Nice attempt though.

Comment: Pillage means to plunder or loot for resources, I don't think a fire does this.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you are:

> Jeff?

Because:

I raze cities and I conquer towns,

I’ll pillage a village and take it all down.

> Hurricane Jeff back in 80's. Hurricanes are bad.

While my wife is up to no good.

> Poor [Jeff Harlingford aka Jeff the Cuckold](http://gta.wikia.com/wiki/Jeff_Harlingford).

I am sometimes mistaken, don’t mistake I!

> [np: Jeff Stadler - I'd Be Mistaken](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dDrs46oxzXc)

I am not one to make food.

> [Jeff Cook](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jeff_Cook) is not a cook.

I don’t belong to a tribe.

> [Jeff Probst](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jeff_Probst) does not belong to a tribe.

And about the title:

> Jeff Richards is a man and also [Canada's most dangerous mind](http://www.jeffrichards.ca/)!

Answer (score 1):

Could be

> Storm

While my wife is up to no good.

> Wind

I am sometimes mistaken, don’t mistake I!

> Storm is mistaken not to have much effect

I am not one to make food.

> Disruption of environment does not provide food

I don’t belong to a tribe

> No tribe take Storm as their origin

Answer (score 0):

Could it be

> A swarm?  Or specifically a swarm of locusts?

I raze cities and I conquer towns,

> Locusts could do this I guess?

I’ll pillage a village and take it all down.

> Raiding crops etc?

While my wife is up to no good.

> Stumped. Could refer to a bee/wasp/hornet queen if the answer is just "a swarm"?

I am sometimes mistaken, don’t mistake I!

> locusts look like grasshoppers/crickets? Bees, wasps and hornets look alike?

I am not one to make food.

> Well that's bee's out, but the others mostly just take food.

I don’t belong to a tribe.

> I belong to a swarm?

Answer (score 0):

It strikes me that this is a lot like the riddle from the Hobbit, so the answer is

> Time

I raze cities and I conquer towns,

I’ll pillage a village and take it all down.

> Time eventually destroys all civilization.

While my wife is up to no good.

> Father time is traditionally associated with Mother Nature, and so she is "up to no good" represents natural disasters.

I am sometimes mistaken, don’t mistake I!

> If you mistake the time, there will be consequences such as being late.

I am not one to make food.

> I suppose this line is to rule out fire as an answer.

I don’t belong to a tribe.

> This line rules out something else, bandits?

Answer (score -1):

In my opinion, you are

> Tsunami

I raze cities and I conquer towns,

I’ll pillage a village and take it all down.

> Tsunami is able to destroy or make everything down

While my wife is up to no good.

> Your wife would be the giant waves in tsunami

I am sometimes mistaken, don’t mistake I!

> Tsunami vs tidal wave

I am not one to make food.

> Tsunami does not make food

I don’t belong to a tribe

> Does not